# Parsing unusal csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

My friend asked me to help him parse eBay csv file and save only couple of important fields, so I thought it will be a good opportunity to learn Python (writing mostly in C for now).

The problem is, eBay csv file format is giving me a hard time:

```
    Numer rekordu sprzedaży,Nazwa użytkownika,Imię i nazwisko kupującego,Numer telefonu kupującego,Adres e-mail kupującego,Adres 1 kupującego,Adres 2 kupującego,Miejscowość kupującego,Województwo kupującego,Kod pocztowy kupującego,Kraj kupującego,Numer przedmiotu,Nazwa przedmiotu,Etykieta niestandardowa,Ilość,Cena sprzedaży,Wysyłka i obsługa,Ubezpieczenie,Koszt płatności za pobraniem,Cena łączna,Forma płatności,Data sprzedaży,Data realizacji transakcji,Data zapłaty,Data wysyłki,Opinia wystawiona,Opinia otrzymana,Uwagi własne,Identyfikator transakcji PayPal,Usługa wysyłkowa,Opcja płatności za pobraniem,Identyfikator transakcji,Identyfikator zamówienia,Szczegóły wersji

"610","xxx","John Rodriguez","(860) 000-00000","mail@yahoo.com","0 Branford Ave Bldg 11","","City","CT","00000","Stany Zjednoczone","330972592582","Honda CBR 900 RR","","1","US $21,49","US $5,50","US $0,00","","US $26,99","PayPal","23-03-2014","23-03-2014","23-03-2014","","Nie","","","4EP58","Standard Shipping from outside US","","9639014","",""
"627","yyy","Name","063100000","mail@orange.fr","Rue barillettes","","st main","Rhône","00000","Francja","3311071","Suzuki SV 650","","1","EUR 15,99","EUR 4,00","EUR 0,00","","EUR 19,99","PayPal","31-03-2014","31-03-2014","31-03-2014","","Nie","","","6E03683046","Livraison standard ? partir de l'étranger","","9659014","",""

Pobrano rekordów: 8,,od ,23-03-2014,15:06:14, do ,11-04-2014,14:32:17
Nazwa sprzedawcy: mail@gmail.com
```

Parsing it with `csv.DictReader`, like in the manual, results with every line like as `none : list[]`

```
import csv

filename = "SalesHistory.csv"

csvfile = open(filename, encoding="iso-8859-2")
input_file = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)

for row in input_file:
    print (row)
```

```py
{None: ['\tNumer rekordu sprzedaży', 'Nazwa użytkownika', 'Imię i nazwisko kupującego', 'Numer telefonu kupującego',
        'Adres e-mail kupującego', 'Adres 1 kupującego', 'Adres 2 kupującego', 'Miejscowość kupującego',
        'Województwo kupującego', 'Kod pocztowy kupującego', 'Kraj kupującego', 'Numer przedmiotu', 'Nazwa przedmiotu',
        'Etykieta niestandardowa', 'Ilość', 'Cena sprzedaży', 'Wysyłka i obsługa', 'Ubezpieczenie',
        'Koszt płatności za pobraniem', 'Cena łączna', 'Forma płatności', 'Data sprzedaży',
        'Data realizacji transakcji', 'Data zapłaty', 'Data wysyłki', 'Opinia wystawiona', 'Opinia otrzymana',
        'Uwagi własne', 'Identyfikator transakcji PayPal', 'Usługa wysyłkowa', 'Opcja płatności za pobraniem',
        'Identyfikator transakcji', 'Identyfikator zamówienia', 'Szczegóły wersji']}
```

instead of, first line read as keys for transactions in other lines.

I read Python CSV manual, looked at some examples, searched Stack Overflow but I still don't know what to do next - most of them cover more 'standard' version of csv.

Any tips to get me moving in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Sorry about that - added

Comment: @pawel.ad, Do you know what the 2 last lines in the csv file are? I'm pretty sure that is going to mess up your reading. Do you need them? If so, how do you want them to be retrieved? They seem... strange

Comment: @BorrajaX They're automaticlly added by eBay and I don't need them. Will try to delete them first then - mayby that will help.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd... your code didn't give me the error that you posted in your question (although I'm using Python 2.7, and you seem to be using a 3.x, maybe is because of that).

Also, the file doesn't start with a blank (empty line), does it? If it does, it'll mess up with the `csv` module. It uses the first line to guess the keys that `csv.DictReader` will use. If there's a blank line at the beginning, it won't be able to guess the keys. You should "clean" the file before trying to parse it with `csv` (removing empty lines should do the trick) or you could read row by row skipping empty rows, but that complicates using `csv.DictReader` (you should get the first non-empty row, consider its values the *keys* for your result dictionary and then read the rest of the rows considering its values as the *values* for your result dictionary... I'd just remove the empty lines from the file before parsing it)

In the code below I've added a `try/catch` block to deal with incomplete lines (such as the last 2 lines in your sample file), but even without it, it was working pretty ok

```
import csv

filename = "SalesHistory.csv"
read_dcts = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    input_file = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
    for i, dct in enumerate(input_file):
        try:
            utf_dict=dict((k.decode('utf-8'), v.decode('utf-8')) \
                          for k, v in dct.items())
            read_dcts.append(utf_dict)
        except AttributeError:
            print "Weird line %d found" % (i + 1)

# Verify:
for i, dct in enumerate(read_dcts):
    print "Dict %d" % (i + 1)
    for k, v in dct.iteritems():
        print "\t%s: %s" % (k, v)
```

If I execute the code above, I get:

```
Weird line 3 found
Weird line 4 found
Dict 1
        Opinia otrzymana: 
        Cena sprzedaży: US $21,49
        [ . . . ]
        Wysyłka i obsługa: US $5,50
        Opcja płatności za pobraniem: 
Dict 2
        Opinia otrzymana: 
        Cena sprzedaży: EUR 15,99
        [ . . . ]
        Wysyłka i obsługa: EUR 4,00
        Opcja płatności za pobraniem
```

I've removed many of the lines loaded, just for clarity's sake but besides that, it should be loading what you wanted.

If you have an update, let me know through a comment.

**EDIT:**

Just in case the file contains an empty line and you don't want to pre-clean it, you can pretty much do "manually" what the `DictReader` class does for you (use the first non-empty line as keys, and the rest of the non-empty lines as values):

```
import csv

filename = "SalesHistory.csv"
read_dcts = []
keys = []
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
    for i, row  in enumerate(reader):
        try:
            if len(row) == 0:
                raise IndexError("Row %d is empty. Should skip" % (i + 1))
            if len(keys) == 0:
                keys = [ val.decode('utf-8') for val in row ]
            elif len(row) == len(keys):
                utf_dict = dict(zip(keys, [ val.decode('utf-8') for val in row ]))
                read_dcts.append(utf_dict)
        except (IndexError, AttributeError), e:
            print "Weird line %d found (got %s)" % ((i + 1), e)

# Verify:
for i, dct in enumerate(read_dcts):
    print "Dict %d" % (i + 1)
    for k, v in dct.iteritems():
        print "\t%s: %s" % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably simlpe function to read a csv file and make keys of the first line in the file and values of other lines.

```
import csv

def dict_from_csv(filename):
    '''
    (file)->list of dictionaries
    Function to read a csv file and format it to a list of dictionaries.
    The headers are the keys with all other data becoming values
    '''

    #open the file and read it using csv.reader()
    #read the file. for each row that has content add it to list mf
    #the keys for our user dict are the first content line of the file mf[0]
    #the values to our user dict are the other lines in the file mf[1:]
    mf = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        my_file = csv.reader(f)
        for row in my_file:
            if any(row):
                mf.append(row)
    file_keys = mf[0]
    file_values = mf[1:]

    #Combine the two lists, turning into a list of dictionaries, using the keys list as the key and the value list as the values
    my_list = []
    for value in file_values:
        my_list.append(dict(zip(file_keys, file_values)))

    #return the list of dictionaries
    return my_list
```